# error while starting self-compiled android in vm

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, alsa

i am getting following errors on starting the android vm (compiled from froyo branch) in virtual-box 4.0.4

```
D/ALSAModule(1985)open called for devices 00000002 in mode 0...

E/ALSALib (1985)external/alsa-lib/src/pcm/pcm.c:2203:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM AndroidPlayback_Speaker_normal

E/ALSALib (1985)external/alsa-lib/src/pcm/pcm.c:2203:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM AndroidPlayback_Speaker

E/ALSALib (1985)external/alsa-lib/src/pcm/pcm.c:2203:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM AndroidPlayback

D/        (1985)[external/alsa-lib/src/pcm/pcm_hw.c]:snd_pcm_hw_prepare
I/ALSAModule(1985)Initialized ALSA PLAYBACK device default
```

it seems the problem is with sound device (or ALSA) but I am not sure. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are missing alsa config in your system image. Check if `/system/etc/asound.conf` is present or not. Try creating a new config file with default configuration. Check [THIS](http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/sylvania-tablets/5841-missing-system-etc-asound-conf-file-producing-unknown-log-messages.html) for more details